# how do my web server know the domain is mine?

Tags: apache, dns, webserver

I bought a domain and registered it on a dns server. But I wonder how my web server know whether the coming request is from my domain. E.g. someone registered his domain on my server too.  Obviously apache should reject other domain's request. I just wanna know more details about how a web server (like apache) detect this. Does it simply set in the config file (maybe **ServerName**?) and do some string comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: By default, if another person points their domain to your website, by default the webpages that are sent to their computer are the same webpages you use for www.yourdomain.com. You can also program your webserver to deny/redirect requests from other domains.

## Long answer (I recommand you read):

A common newbie misconception is that domains are "TIED" to a web server. However, that is not true. They are completely different and somewhat unrelated. A domain is just shorthand for an IP address that correlates to your web server. An IP address is really what is TIED with your web server.

For example:

www.example.com could 'resolve'/correlate to 1.1.1.1
and
www.randomdomain.com could also resolve to 1.1.1.1

If 1.1.1.1 is the ip address your web server is correlated to, THEN these requests will both get sent to your web server.

Now, if you think about it, with this logic, you should be able to access your web server by just typing in 1.1.1.1 That is true!

## Real world example:

www.google.com goes to Google

172.217.6.78 also goes to Google because 172.217.6.78 is one of the web servers google.com will correlate/resolve to. Go ahead and type 172.217.6.78 into your web browser. It will take you to google.com.

DNS servers point your domain to the IP address of your web server.

## On your webserver:

Your server will run a software that will respond to requests it gets from the outside internet. This software will usually know how to respond to this requests using the correct syntax and also be able to handle multiple requests at the same time. When this software gets a request, it will load a file (that you specify) and send it to the user/client.

Common examples of this software include Apache (most famous/popular - runs like 40% of all websites you browse including facebook.com) and nginx (becoming more popular).
The default config of an Apache/nginx/etc web server is to serve that user (at port 80) the documents that are in the 'www' folder. However, (for Apache) if you would like to serve multiple domains on one web server (www.example.com & login.example.com), you would usually create virtual hosts. Creating virtual hosts can be done by editing your Apache configuration file. (If you're hosting on GoDaddy/namecheap or something similar, you won't have access to this.)

An example of a basic virtual host could be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> #80 for port 80 - the standard port for unencrypted web traffic
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /where/your/web/files/are/located
<VirtualHost>
```

You could then create another virtual host to reject/forward another domain's traffic

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.randomotherdomain.com
#here, you could either serve new content to this domain using "DocumentRoot" or you can forward all traffic to your website
Redirect / http://www.yourdomain.com
<VirtualHost>
```

## However, by default, if another person points their domain to your website, by default the webpages that are sent to their computer are the same webpages you use for www.yourdomain.com